# I need to build something similar to this html audio example

Tags: javascript, html, audio

For my PHD I need to build something similar to [this](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/MIDIDrums/index.html) but with also a bass sound integrated. Both sounds should come from a samples library to avoid the usual boring MIDI sounds.

I am wondering if it is possible to create such a system and which technology I could use.
I know this question involves personal opinions, so maybe it's better if we refer to the example I provided, understanding how that can be achieved.

---

**Edit:** The solution should be web based, sorry if the question is a bit unclear

Comment: The URL that you had quoted has a GITHub account along with the source code available here -> https://github.com/cwilso/MIDIDrums

Comment: Thank you David. I checked that already, but what I actually need is a bit different. I will be using genetic algorithms and a couple of neural networks to generate a population of bass riffs. That will be done on server side. The riffs will then need to be played on client side. I am wondering if I could send a MIDI sequence to the client side and use some good sampled sounds instead of midi sounds, or if I should create the riff in some audio format (mps or ogg) on server side and then send the file to the client. The user has just to listen and to evaluate them. @David R

Comment: @Maxyone I got your requirement, Checkout these libraries please, **MudCube-Midi.js** - https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js  and **Midi Synth** - https://github.com/cwilso/midi-synth

Comment: @David R - Thanks! That's what I need. I saw that in one of the examples they use soundfonts, which are sampled sounds, so it is what I need, thank you again!

Comment: @Maxyone Cool!.. Can you please accept my answer given below then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some great libraries available in the GITHub which can meet your requirement. Check below URL's

**MudCube-Midi.js** - [MIDI.js](http://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js%20and)

**Midi Synth** - [Midi Synth](http://github.com/cwilso/midi-synth)

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be web based (your question is a bit unclear)? Otherwise, check out kvraudio.com. On their forums there are discussions on how to create software-based synths. There are several frameworks that let you do this rather easil, even without coding.

Comment: Hello, yes, it has to be web based. I already have a desktop version which uses midi sounds but it is not good enough for what I want to achieve.